# Spring Security & Logbook - getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, logbook

When I use Logbook auto configuration with Spring Security with Spring Boot app packaged as war and deployed to Tomcat and try to access non existent url, I get

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Mar 07 18:14:22 CET 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
```

I have prepared minimal example to reproduce it [here](https://github.com/davidjirovec/Logbook-Spring-Security-Problem)

without Logbook it works as expected - basic auth is required

without Spring Security it works as expected - not found error message is shown

when packaged as jar with embedded Tomcat it works perfectly

The problem is not present only when accessing non existent url - if there would be any controllers in my example, you would not be able to access them neither.

Comment: There should be a stack trace somewhere in your logfiles.

Comment: Yes there is, but it does not seem very helpful to me. I even debugged through all the filters involved in the request processing, but still I don't understand what exactly is cause of the issue. Because the example to reproduce the issue is very simple, basically just auto configuration of the used libraries, it seems to be a bug in some of the libraries. I would be glad for fix or at least some workaround.